# client side routing to component on browser refresh throws 404 error

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-router-v4, react-scripts

I have a react app created with the create-react-app template and want it be deployed on IIS as a part of another application folder.

On client navigation after loading the navigated component is loaded but when i refresh the url from the browser i get a 404 error

For example:
i build using npm run build with package.json

[image: package.json]

I have also set the base name to the Router component

[image: BrowserRouter]

on open of the react site and navigation to the component "Admin" it shows the component properly. But when i reload the same url by refreshing from the browser refresh button i get an 404 error page not found.

When i run using the npm start it runs with http://localhost:3000/ as default and on component navigation changes the url to http://localhost:3000/admin . here if i refresh from the browser it loads the page and navigates properly showing the navigated component.

What am i missing to make this work ?

[image]

Comment: How are you able to solve this?

Comment: The react app was placed in a folder and the web.config where the url rewrite was not a part of it hence added the web.config at the folder level where the react app was place along with routes.

Comment: I am facing this kind of issue too and I dont know the workaround yet. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651771/react-production-build-shows-404-on-page-refresh